# Ротация логов в полночь

Tags: golang, логирование

Имеется код на go, хочу сделать чтоб в 0 часов и 0 минут произошло замена имени файла логов на новую дату в имени файла лога. Подскажите где ошибся.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    rotatelogs "github.com/lestrrat/go-file-rotatelogs"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func initiLogger() {
    path := "/home/john/logs/PS"
    h, _ := time.ParseDuration("0h00m")
    var writer, err = rotatelogs.New(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", path, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        //fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", path, "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S"),
        //rotatelogs.WithLinkName("/home/john/logs/current"),
        rotatelogs.WithMaxAge(time.Hour*24),
        rotatelogs.WithRotationTime(h),
        //rotatelogs.WithRotationTime(time.Hour*24),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to Initialize Log File %s", err)
    }
    log.SetOutput(writer)

    //log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lmicroseconds)
    //log.SetPrefix("________________")
    log.SetFlags(5)
    return
}

func main() {
    initiLogger()
    fmt.Println("Start !!!", time.Now() )
    log.Println("Start !!!", time.Now() )
    for i := 0; i < 86400; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        log.Printf("Hello, World! Its - 5")
    }
    log.Println("Done !!!", time.Now() )
    fmt.Println("Done !!!", time.Now() )
}
```

Comment: Так-то это дело logrotate'а.

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", path, "%Y-%m-%d"),` замените на `fmt.Sprintf("%s/log.%s", path, "%Y-%m-%d"),` потому что должен быть путь до файла, а не до папки

Answer (score 0):

Может кому поможет, как я решил данный вопрос

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    rotatelogs "github.com/lestrrat-go/file-rotatelogs"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func initiLogger() {
    
    path := "PS"
    var writer, err = rotatelogs.New(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", path, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        rotatelogs.WithMaxAge(time.Hour*24),
        rotatelogs.WithRotationTime(time.Hour*24),
        
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to Initialize Log File %s", err)
    }

    log.SetFlags(5)
    log.SetOutput(writer)
    return
}

func main() {
    initiLogger()

    fmt.Println("Start !!!", time.Now())
    log.Println("Start !!!", time.Now())
    for i := 0; i < 90; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
        log.Printf("Hello, World! Its - 5")
    }
    log.Println("Done !!!", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("Done !!!", time.Now())
}
```